# Cannot read propery afs (Angularfirestore) of undefined on collection.set()

Tags: angular, typescript, angularfire

I use the following code, to iterate over a collection of data, and change a field if the email matches. Note that the code crashes on the set. The iteration works just fine. afs is initialized as AngularFirestore

```
onChangeRole(email) {
  this.afs.collection("users").get().toPromise().then(function (querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
      // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
      console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());

      if (doc.data().email == email) {
        this.afs.collection("users").doc(doc.id).set({
          role: 2
        })
      }
    });
  });
}
```

But im receiving:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'afs' of undefined
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'afs' of undefined

Where afs is AngularFirestore

```
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection , AngularFirestoreDocument} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
```

Comment: is ur `constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) { }` like this

Comment: yes @SouravDutta in fact the console.log displays the whole collection, so afs is working for the .get()   . ITs only in the .set() where i receive the error

Comment: try this below

`onChangeRole(email) {
  const usersColl = this.afs.collection("users"); usersColl.get().toPromise().then(function (querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) { // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
      console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
      if (doc.data().email == email) {
        usersColl.doc(doc.id).set({ role: 2 }, { merge: true })
      }
    });
  });
}`

Comment: @SouravDutta works fine, thats it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
onChangeRole(email) {
  const usersColl = this.afs.collection("users");
  usersColl.get().toPromise().then(function (querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
      console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
      if (doc.data().email == email) {
        usersColl.doc(doc.id).set(
          { role: 2 },
          { merge: true }
        )
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialise it in the constructor, then you will be able to use it with **this.afs** like you are trying to.

Per example:

```
constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) { }
```

EDIT:
change the funciton word for arrow function usage:

```
this.afs.collection("users").get().toPromise().then( querySnapshot => {
      querySnapshot.forEach( doc => {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());

        if (doc.data().email == email) {
          this.afs.collection("users").doc(doc.id).set({
            role: 2
          })
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: its already initialized , in fact the code crashed on the set, the .get() which uses .afs too works fine

Comment: Could you try 
`onChangeRole(email) {
  const usersColl = this.afs.collection("users");
  usersColl.get().toPromise().then(function (querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
      // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
      console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());

      if (doc.data().email == email) {
        usersColl.doc(doc.id).set({
          role: 2
        })
      }
    });
  });
}`
Just curious about that

Comment: I tested it, and it deleted the email field , althought now it doesnt cause an error, i was looking at just setting a new role

Comment: I edited the answer without the **function**, you should be using this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions